# Vue component testing with Jest error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue component with the following template below. It receives an object as a prop. First, it is pulled from the backend on `created()` in `Admin.vue`, passed as an array to `OrderList`, looped over, then passed as an individual order to `Order`. The `ShowOrder` component in `<router-link>` displays the individual order on its own page.

```html
<template v-if="order ? order : error">
  <div class="order-container -shadow">
    <div class="order-number">
      <p>{{ order.orderId }}</p>
      <p>{{ order.daySelected }}</p>
      <p>{{ order.timeSelected }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-info">
      <h2>{{ order.userInfo.name }}</h2>
      <p>
        {{ order.userInfo.street }},
        {{ order.userInfo.city }}
      </p>
      <p v-if="order.userInfo.apt">
        {{ order.userInfo.apt }}
      </p>
      <p>{{ order.userInfo.phone }}</p>
         ...
         ...

          <router-link :to="{ name: 'ShowOrder', params: { id: order.orderId, order: order }}"
      >Show Details</router-link
    >
   </div> 
  </template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Order",
  props: {
    order: {
      type: Object,
      default: function() {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      error: "Error"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

My `Order.spec.js` is as follows:

```js
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter();
const $route = {
  path: '"/show-order/:id"'
};

shallowMount(Order, {
  localVue,
  router,
  stubs: ["router-link", "router-view"]
});

const mockOrder = {
  orderId: 123,
  chocolateChip: 24,
  oatmeal: 0,
  campfire: 12,
  daySelected: "Wed Jan 27",
  timeSelected: "2:30 - 3:00",
  userInfo: {
    apt: "",
    city: "Port ",
    email: "k@gmail.com",
    street: " Point Road",
    phone: "(123)446-1980",
    name: "Mr.Smith"
  }
};

describe("Order.vue", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Order, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        order: mockOrder,
        $route
      }
    });
    console.log(wrapper.html());
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The error I receive looks like this:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/Order.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

      72 |   flex-flow: column wrap;
      73 |   margin-top: 1em;
    > 74 |   transition: all 0.2s linear;
         |                                                             ^
      75 | }
      76 | 
      77 | .order-container:hover {
```

I can't even get a snapshot test to work. I read many of the other similar questions here with this error, and tried the `v-if` in the template to wait for the data before the component loads. What is going on here? And if this is an object error, why in the console is there a pointer to my scoped css and not `order.userInfo.name`?

I also, tried changing from `created()` in `Admin.vue` to `mounted()`.

In `Order.vue`, I tried adding the object to make it reactive based on these [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties).

```
  data() {
    return {
      error: "Error",
      orderItem: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.orderItem = Object.assign({}, this.order);
    console.log(this.orderItem, "line 65");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `shallowMount()` twice: once outside of your test without the `mockOrder` (and this call is not necessary), and again inside your test with the `mockOrder`.

```js
// Order.spec.js
shallowMount(Order, { localVue }) // ❌ no props, but no need for this call

describe("Order.vue", () => {
  shallowMount(Order, {
    localVue,
    propsData: {
      order: mockOrder
    }
  })
})
```

The first call is causing the error because its `order` prop defaults to the empty object, so `order.userInfo` would be `undefined`, leading to the error for `order.userInfo.name`.

The solution is to remove the unnecessary first call to `shallowMount()`.

Comment: To others that follow, this turned out to Not be a reactivity issue due to the child being nested, this was a testing implementation error only. The correction worked and I went back to created() in Admin, and in Order, I removed orderItem from data property and the mounted hook to add orderItem as a reactive property.